# C# EWS read 500 email accounts

Tags: c#, exchangewebservices

I need to create an application to read 500 exchange email accounts, I am using EWS and AutodiscoverUrl.

As per Microsoft documentation is a best practice cache the autodiscover response and use autodiscover for each mailbox one wants to read, I have two questions:

- For caching I am planning to use the System.Runtime.Caching dll; is it this the best approach? Can you advise on a better solution?
- Should I use autodiscover for every mailbox that I want to read, even though all they are in the same server?

P.S

I'm using EWS Managed API and want to cache only the EWS URL.

Answer (score 1):

The autodiscover response is just [XML](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb204082(v=exchg.150).aspx). In theory, you can cache it any number of ways (e.g. the AppDomain cache, Caching application block) but System.Runtime.Caching.MemoryCache seems to be the recommended in process cache for .Net 4 and up. If your are talking about a web app, I guess you might consider the HttpCache.

Regarding caching for each mailbox, I think the answer is yes. You would cache the Autodiscover endpoint information, and then invoke [GetUserSettings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj900154(v=exchg.150).aspx) for each mailbox, using the cached Autodiscover information.

Comment: I just have one question regarding autodiscover for each Mailbox, should I run it for each account even though they all are on the samt server.

Comment: I think you need to run it only once for each domain, and cache the response